# NetworkError using Nginx for the Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

My project is Symfony 4.3 and PHP 7.3.
The communication from client is GraphQl although I am using GraphiQl now.
 - Using Symfony Built-in server the requests work fine.
 - Using Nginx server the requests fail caused by "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource". No errors in Firefox console, no errors in Symfony log file but the backend recieves the request.

I have the following setting in Nginx with CORS part:

```
server {
    listen 802 default_server;
    listen [::]:802;

    root /project/public/;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
   }

   # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
   # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
   location ~ \.php$ {
       return 404;
   }

   error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

}
```

This is the browser in a test.
[image: Browser in a test]

I have deployed the app in a external server by cpanel and it works.